# Issue update menu title link to page with an apostrophe in WordPress with Timber

Tags: timber

I got an issue on the auto-update of menu item title when the page title is change but only if there is an apostrophe in the page title.

I'm using Timber 1.22, Wordpress 6.4 and PHP 8.1 on this website.
But I noticed the same issue with a site working with Timber 2.

I tried other type of characters that could create encoding issue like accents or hyphens but no problem with those. Menu item title update properly.

I've disable all of my custom theme functions and hooks, the issue persisted.
When I disable Timber, the title update work with the apostrophe.

Any idea where this can come from ?